# Java : Understanding CDI in an Oracle WebSockets tutorial

Tags: java, websocket, cdi

I am trying to understand the following Oracle tutorial about WebSockets:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

This is my first time seeing CDI, scopes, and injection. I would like to understand how the following code specifies how many instances of DeviceWebSocketServer and DeviceSessionHandler will exist per session.

Here is the pertinent code from Oracle: (I added the print statements)

```
package org.example.websocket;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;   
import javax.inject.Inject;
....

@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer {

    @Inject
    private DeviceSessionHandler sessionHandler;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        System.out.println("OnOpen. Server Endpoint id: " + this);
        sessionHandler.addSession(session);
    }

    ....

}

package org.example.websocket;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import org.example.model.Device;
....

@ApplicationScoped
public class DeviceSessionHandler {
    private int deviceId = 0;
    private final Set<Session> sessions = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<>();


    public void addSession(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Adding session. Session handler id: " + this);
        sessions.add(session);
        for (Device device : devices) {
            JsonObject addMessage = createAddMessage(device);
            sendToSession(session, addMessage);
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

Both classes use the Application scope, yet for each new session, a new DeviceWebSocketServer instance is created, while only one instance of DeviceSessionHandler is used among all instances of it. To demonstrate this, here is an output of my print statements after I opened two sessions:

Info:   OnOpen. Server Endpoint id: org.example.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer@769f6d85

Info:   Adding session. Session handler id: org.example.websocket.DeviceSessionHandler@4c8caf5

Info:   OnOpen. Server Endpoint id: org.example.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer@5e29b620

Info:   Adding session. Session handler id: org.example.websocket.DeviceSessionHandler@4c8caf5

So, if the scope doesn't determine the number of instances per session, how is this determined?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CDI is proxy based.  The underlying reference may be different, but the instance is considered to be the same.  When you call onOpen multiple times, do you see all of the entries collected?

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. So you're saying there is only one instance of the DeviceWebSocketServer, but multiple references? What does "entries" refer to in this context? Thanks!

Comment: Almost.  The proxy is pointing to a reference of that bean.  CDI will manage the state of the underlying references, even if multiple instances of the bean are created.  That's why its recommended to use `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` rather than constructors doing work.